# Accessing a variable of an object using dynamic value

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter, object

I am creating a database call within the Codeigniter framework which will call one of three rates (cells in the database) depending on what is passed to the database call function.

Here is the my model function which will query the database:

```
public function getRate($options) { 
        $query = "SELECT * FROM staff_rates WHERE staff_id = " . (int)$options['id'] . " AND month = '" . strtolower($options['month']) . "' AND year = " . $options['year'];
        $result = $this->db->query($query);     
        $rate = $options['type'] . "_rate";         
        return $result->result()->{$rate};
    }
```

As you can see, an array is passed to the function which contains a value called of the key 'type'. This type can be one of three strings, 'attrition', 'movement' and 'occupancy' and there are three corresponding cells in the database, 'attrition_rate', 'movement_rate' and 'occupancy_rate'.

I only want this function to return the value from the cell that I have passed to the function, so as you can see in my code, I try to build the name of the cell I require ($rate = $options['type'] . "_rate";) in order to pass it back to my controller.

```
Severity: Notice

Message: Trying to get property of non-object

Filename: models/assessment_model.php

Line Number: 523
```

This is referencing the line of code:

```
return $result->result()->{$rate};
```

Is it not possible for me to access variables of objects in this fashion (as in using dynamic variables)?

Thanks

Comment: What is your database field name ?

Comment: 'attrition_rate', 'movement_rate' and 'occupancy_rate' are the database field names and 'attrition', 'movement' and 'occupancy' are the type strings. I then build the field name to access from the object using the line '$rate = $options['type'] . "_rate";'.

Comment: $result->result() returns an array not an object .  You can probably access it like this `return $result->result()[$rate]` refer  http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/results.html.

Comment: i got your problem i posting my message in answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$result->result()

this will return you array of object 
  you can use

```
 $result->row();
```

to get single result

Comment: I then used this to access my dynamic variable:$rate = $options['type'] . "_rate"; return $result->row()->{$rate};